# How to fetch a specific data from a url?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an android app which fetches data by visiting https://demo.vtiger.com/webservice.php?operation=getchallenge&username=admin.

The output of above url is **{"success":true,"result":{"token":"53ba663902fd3","serverTime":1404724793,"expireTime":1404725093}}**

But I want only the value of "token", so How can I fetch it from the result of above url?

Thanks for ur help.

Comment: You need to get the json first and then parse the json later

Comment: try the json parsing tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create JSONParser class in your application project.
Refer Below link for JSONParser class:

```
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-json-parsing-url-example.html
```

then call it from your class

```
JSONParser jp=new JSONParser();

JsonObject object=jp.getJSONFromUrl(your url);
JsonObject object2=object.getJsonObject("result");

String Token=object2.getString("token");
```

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class to make an object from this json string.

Then get a token you want from the composed object.

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = "{\"success\":true,\"result\":{\"token\":\"53ba663902fd3\",\"serverTime\":1404724793,\"expireTime\":1404725093}}";
JsonParser parser = new com.google.gson.JsonParser();
JsonElement elem = parser.parse(json);
String token = elem.getAsJsonObject().get("result").getAsJsonObject().get("token").getAsString();
System.out.print(token);
```